# How do i handle multiple http requests with $q all angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I am trying to wrapp my head around $q angular library. In my routeprovider i would like to get all my data from the server and store it in localStorage. But for some reason the resolve dont seem to wait for all http request to finish before routing to selectMedia. From my understanding reading the angular docs this should work but it doesn´t. Have i totally missunderstood the concept or am i my thinking right?

```
         $routeProvider.           
            when('/', {
            redirectTo : '/selectMedia',
            resolve: {  
                data: function ($q, backendApi, localStorage, network, route, loginService){
                    var prices = function () {
                        var defer = $q.defer();
                        backendApi.prices.get(function (data) {
                            localStorage.setItem("videoPrice", data.VideoPrice);
                            localStorage.setItem("imagePrice", data.ImagePrice);
                            localStorage.setItem("prices", data.SliderPrices);
                            localStorage.setItem("priceSuffix", data.PriceSuffix);
                            defer.resolve();
                        }, defer.resolve);  
                        return defer.promise;
                    };
                    var validFormats = function () {
                        var defer = $q.defer(); 
                        backendApi.validFormats.get(function (formats) {
                            localStorage.setItem("validFormats", formats);
                            defer.resolve();
                        }, defer.resolve);
                        return defer.promise;
                    };
                    var videoFormats = function () {
                        var defer = $q.defer(); 
                        backendApi.videoFormats.get(function (videoFormats) {
                            localStorage.setItem("videoFormats", videoFormats); 
                            defer.resolve();
                        }, defer.resolve);
                        return defer.promise;
                    };
                    var categories = function () {
                        var defer = $q.defer();
                        backendApi.categories.get(function (data){
                            localStorage.setItem("categories", data.Categories);
                            defer.resolve();
                        },defer.resolve);   
                        return defer.promise;
                    };
                    var renewToken = function () {
                        var defer = $q.defer();
                        loginService.renewToken(defer.resolve);
                        return defer.promise;
                    };

                    if(network.isOnline()){                 
                        var promises = [renewToken(), categories(), videoFormats(), validFormats(), prices()];
                        return $q.all(promises);
                    }
                    else if(!network.isOnline() && localStorage.length === 0){
                        route('/error');
                    }
                }   
            }
        });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the controller for the route being specified in the route definition. I guess you have set it via `ngController` at the view level. The `resolve` block is skipped when you don't have a controller specified in the definition.

**4/23 UPDATE**

The definition of the `resolve` property extracted from the official docs:

> An optional map of dependencies **which should be injected into the
>   controller**. If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be
>   resolved and converted to a value before the controller is
>   instantiated and the $routeChangeSuccess event is fired.

According to the definition, the design purpose of the `resolve` property is to have a way to inject dependencies into the controller associated with a route.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the resolve block doesn´t seem to be skipped and why do i need to specify a controller? All i want to do is save my data from the server in localStorage so i can access the data antwhere in the app.

Comment: @bassen - I have updated my answer above. Using `resolve` without a controller is not what `resolve` is designed for. If I were you, I would try to use a controller just to see if that makes a difference and then work from there.

Comment: @bassen - I am not completely sure how you want to use your `data` service. My guess is that you want it as a singleton object that gets loaded up when the app starts and its users don't get to access it until then. If so, you don't need to use `resolve` at all. You can simply use AngularJS service + promise + module.run(). Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xVUHm6Ddo2Xx1b93cTDp?p=preview) that demonstrates what I mean. There are comments in the code explaining what the code is doing. Note on the view, I use `ngShow` to show the content only if the promise is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your answears. What i wanted to do was to save all serverdata when the app started. When('/') runs before routing to a page. That means it has no associated controller. I have now got it to work. The problem was that i couldn´t redirect to a page after resolve. My solution was to use  $q.all().then redirect to a page.